# How can I transform my data to long format, creating a new variable without a current variable to support its values?

Tags: r, transformation

I am trying to reshape data from wide format into long format. My current variables are "State", "Reg2016", "Voted2016", "Turnout2016", "Reg2012", "Voted2012", "Turnout2012", and "TurnoutDelta."

I need to get this data into long format, creating a new variable called "Year" that will either equal 2012 or 2016.

Dataframe (cut some variables off to fit)

```
## State #### Reg2016 #### Voted2016 #### Turnout2016 #### Reg2012 #### Voted 2012  ##
AK             x               x               x              x              x
AL             x               x               x              x              x
```

Is there a way to extrapolate this new variable based on the data that I have? This is for a class project and this was the professor's suggestion.

I tried variations of the pivot_longer function with no luck.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example using dput() ?

Comment: Please read the instructions at the top fo the [tag:r] tag page on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `tidyverse` package where this sort of thing is done all the time.

```
library(tidyverse)
state_names <- c("Alaska", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "American Samoa", "Arizona", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "District ", "of Columbia", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Guam", "Hawaii", "Iowa", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Massachusetts", "Maryland", "Maine", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Missouri", "Mississippi", "Montana", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Nebraska", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "Nevada", "New York", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Virginia", "Virgin Islands", "Vermont", "Washington", "Wisconsin", "West Virginia", "Wyoming")
wide_cnames <- c("Reg2016","Voted2016","Turnout2016","Reg2012","Voted2012","Turnout2012","TurnoutDelta")
vote_data_wide <- data.frame(state=state_names)
for (cname in wide_cnames){
  vote_data_wide[cname] <- sample(1e6:1e7,56)
}
vote_data_long <- pivot_longer(vote_data_wide, names_to="label", values_to="number", cols=all_of(wide_cnames))
vote_data_long$Year <- gsub("[a-zA-Z]*","",vote_data_long$label) %>% as.numeric
vote_data_long$label <- gsub("[0-9*$]","",vote_data_long$label)
```

This will give you a bunch of `TurnoutDelta` fields with `NA` for Year.

```
   state   label         number  Year
   <fct>   <chr>          <int> <dbl>
 1 Alaska  Reg          2237300  2016
 2 Alaska  Voted        5906315  2016
 3 Alaska  Turnout      8345919  2016
 4 Alaska  Reg          5351097  2012
 5 Alaska  Voted        7196930  2012
 6 Alaska  Turnout      5285145  2012
 7 Alaska  TurnoutDelta 2564558    NA
 8 Alabama Reg          8753718  2016
 9 Alabama Voted        3425493  2016
10 Alabama Turnout      6141827  2016
```